# Using grpc.Core, cold not find Google Namespace in C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am getting lots of missing dependency errors after installing GRPC.Tools NuGet package, and building Greeter.cs file from Greeter.proto

The Greeter.cs file require some google API, evidently this wasn't installed by Grpc.Tools

What else do I need to install, what am I missing?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GreeterService;
using Grpc.Core;

namespace gRPCtest
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello, " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }

    public class Server : Form
    {
        public Server()
        {
            Text = "Server Window";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);

            const int port = 50051;

            Server server = new Server
            {
                Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterServiceImpl()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine($"Greeter service is listening on port {port}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
    public class Client : Form
    {
        public Client()
        {
            Text = "Client Window";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);

            const string serverAddress = "localhost";
            const int port = 50051;

            Channel channel = new Channel($"{serverAddress}:{port}", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

            string name = "John";
            var request = new HelloRequest { Name = name };

            var reply = client.SayHello(request);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {reply.Message}");

            channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the child window
            Server serverForm = new Server();
            serverForm.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the child window
            Client clientForm = new Client();
            clientForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the Google.Protobuf NuGet package - the C# runtime library for Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 0):

When you check your first error message, it says *The type or namespace name 'Greeter' could not be found*. The `Greeter.cs` file is [generated](https://protobuf.dev/reference/csharp/csharp-generated/) by the protobuf compiler `protoc`. In any project where you want to create the code-behind C# files from the protobuf files , you need the following NuGet packages:

```
Grpc.Tools
Google.Protobuf
```

or a package that references them, like the `Grpc.AspNetCore` package, which is [currently recommended to be used for server side gRPC](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/), `Grpc.Core` is in maintenance mode.

When building the project, the `Greeter.cs` file will be generated by protoc, and can be found in your build output (you also need to define in VS Studio in the file property of the protobuf file that the "Build Action" (in the file property) is "Protobuf compiler").